# Moving from a scene to a view controller - Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I am working on an iPhone app using Storyboard and I need to handle view changes from one view controller to another one. I have:

```
-INTROViewController.m
-INTROscene.m (this is a SKScene laid out by the above controller)

-UpgradeViewController.m
```

There is a sprite button in `INTROscene.m` and when I press it, it triggers a notification which is seen by its view controller (`INTROViewController.m`) and this triggers the switch to another view controller (`UpgradeViewController.m`). If I use **Option 1**, (which even adds a delay in order to make sure that the first view has appeared), it triggers the error below:

**“Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!”**

I’ve found a way of switching view controllers without triggering this error **(Option 2)** but the visual effect is horrible, with a little lag showing an empty screen between the two views. Moreover I cannot use any of the nice transitions which are available using `modalTransitionStyle`.

What is the correct way of switching between views in this situation?

In my AppDelegate I don’t have a root view controller (and I don’t know how this should be set up). Is that the reason why I get the error? If so, how could I implement it? Cheers!

```
//Option 1 (triggers the error above)
  -(void)TransitionTo_Upgrades_ViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        //Take from INTROViewController to UpgradeViewController 
        UpgradeViewController *controllerUPGRADES = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Upgrades_storyboard"];
        controllerUPGRADES.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self performSelector:@selector(NowGotoUPRADES) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }

    - (void)NowGotoUPRADES
    {
        [self presentViewController:controllerUPGRADES animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

//Option 2 (no error but horrible effect)
-(void)TransitionTo_OPTIONS_ViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
{
        [self performSelector:@selector(NowGotoOPTIONS) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
- (void)NowGotoOPTIONS
{
        //Take from INTROViewController to UpgradeViewController 
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *DesiredViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Options_storyboard"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:DesiredViewController];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this same problem and have found that there is no solution as once you move from scene to scene in a view controller, you are unable to move to other view controllers as you have moved out of the proper hierarchy. My solution to this was to have my other view controllers as skscenes, however you may want to have most of your skscenes as view controllers whilst also not moving between scenes whilst on the same view controller.

Hope this helps. Reply if you need any clarification.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for confirming my doubts. It's crazy though that this cannot be done! Did you say that it is possible to set the whole skscene directly inside the view controller without having to use another class? Have I understood correctly? That could be a solution

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. You can have multiple skscenes using just one view controller.